# React AG-Grid Time Stamps in DateTime Picker not matching with data values / AG-Grid datetime filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, ag-grid, flatpickr

[DEMO ON STACK BLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-phvewm?file=src/DataGrid.jsx)

I'm using [AG-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/getting-started/), a data table package, in a React project of mine. This table holds a set of DateTime values. In order to filter the DateTime values in the table, I am using a slightly modified version of the [example DateTime filter provided by the AG-Grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-date/?), which uses the [Flatpickr package](https://flatpickr.js.org/).

The DateTime values in my table are in ISO string format. When I make a selection via the calendar and clock, the values in the filter inputs are not the same as what I am selecting on the calendar and they do not match the values in the table cells.

Here is a screenshot showing the difference between the calendar selection and the input:
[image: Picture of undesired behavior]

And here is a screenshot of the results of the applied filters and how they do not match the inputs:
[image: Undesired behavior after results are applied]

I've been stumped by this problem for a long time, so if anyone can help me figure out why the values in the inputs, calendar and filter results are not matching up, it would be a great help.

[DEMO ON STACK BLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-phvewm?file=src/DataGrid.jsx)

---

**DataGrid.jsx** ([AG-Grid Docs for reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/getting-started/))

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import DateTimePicker from './DateTimePicker';
import DATES from './data/DATES.json';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const DataGrid = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(DATES);

  const COLUMN_DEFINITION = [
    {
      field: 'dateTime',
      headerName: 'Date Time',
      filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        defaultOption: 'inRange',
        // Filtering function for DateTime values:
        comparator: function(filterLocalDate, cellValue) {
          filterLocalDate = new Date(filterLocalDate);
          cellValue = new Date(cellValue);
          let filterBy = filterLocalDate.getTime();
          let filterMe = cellValue.getTime();
          if (filterBy === filterMe) {
            return 0;
          }

          if (filterMe < filterBy) {
            return -1;
          }

          if (filterMe > filterBy) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={COLUMN_DEFINITION}
        rowData={rowData}
        defaultColDef={{
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          filterParams: {
            buttons: ['apply', 'clear', 'reset', 'cancel']
          }
        }}
        frameworkComponents={{
          agDateInput: DateTimePicker
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataGrid;
```

**DateTimePicker.jsx** ([Flatpickr Docs for reference](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/)):

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useRef,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle
} from 'react';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';

export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [picker, setPicker] = useState(null);
  const refFlatPickr = useRef();
  const refInput = useRef();

  const onDateChanged = selectedDates => {
    const [selectedDate] = selectedDates;
    setDate(selectedDate);
    props.onDateChanged();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPicker(
      flatpickr(refFlatPickr.current, {
        onChange: onDateChanged,
        dateFormat: 'Z',
        wrap: true,
        enableTime: true,
        enableSeconds: true,
        time_24hr: true
      })
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (picker) {
      picker.calendarContainer.classList.add('ag-custom-component-popup');
    }
  }, [picker]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (picker) {
      picker.setDate(date);
    }
  }, [date, picker]);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getDate() {
      return date;
    },

    setDate(date) {
      setDate(date);
    },

    setInputPlaceholder(placeholder) {
      if (refInput.current) {
        refInput.current.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder);
      }
    },

    setInputAriaLabel(label) {
      if (refInput.current) {
        refInput.current.setAttribute('aria-label', label);
      }
    }
  }));

  return (
    <div
      className="ag-input-wrapper custom-date-filter"
      role="presentation"
      ref={refFlatPickr}
    >
      <input type="text" ref={refInput} data-input style={{ width: '100%' }} />
      <a class="input-button" title="clear" data-clear>
        <i class="fa fa-times" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes to your example:

1. commented out the property `dateFormat: 'Z'` inside the date picker. This is causing the selected date and the date inside the input box of the date picker to have a different format.
2. inside `filterParams.comparator` I've removed the 'Z' appended to the end of the `cellValue` string. It seems that when calling `new Date(cellValue)` the date is not giving the correct hour value as the `cellValue` string. So to fix this, I simply just removed `'Z'`:

```
cellValue = new Date(cellValue.slice(0, -1));
```

See this implemented here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6dwqvh?file=src%2FDataGrid.jsx

Comment: I hope that you see this before it is deleted, but thank you so much!